# Ruby Error: syntax error, unexpected tGVAR, expecting $end

Tags: ruby, syntax-error

I am getting Ruby Error: `syntax error, unexpected tGVAR, expecting $end.`

I am using Mechanize to access a website and then I need to enter data into the form to search. When I `pp page` the site to get the form information I get:

```
#<Mechanize::Form
<name nil>
<method "POST">
<action "">
<fields
...
...
[text:0xb43f9c type: text name: ct100$MainContent$txtNumber value: ]
...
```

My code that is throwing this is:

```
Check_form = page.form()
Check_form.ct100$MainContent$txtNumber = 'J520518'
```

Any ideas on what is causing the error? Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: @AlexKliuchnikau Thanks for the edit. You got to it before I could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is not a valid variable or syntactically valid method name, you should use the alternate method to fetch or assign the values:

```
check_form = page.form
check_form['ct100$MainContent$txtNumber'] = 'J520518'
```

Variables are of the form `@x` for class instance variables, `@@x` for class variables, `$x` for global variables and `x` for plain variables, but in all cases the variable must consist of a letter or underscore followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. `$` cannot appear anywhere but the beginning, and when it does that means "global variable", something rarely used in most Ruby programming.

Comment: As an additional note, variables that begin with capital letters are declared as constants, which is probably not what you had in mind here.

Comment: I assume you mean the item that I am entering into the search box ('J520518'). Since it's a search item (the value) that souldn't matter. If you are refering to the items in the bracket, that's out of my realm of control. I personally wouldn't have designed a website that used variable identifiers as part of a form name. Now I have a new problem which I will submit as a new question. (This website it being such a pain). Thank you so much for all your help!!! Cheers!

Comment: I mean `Check_form` is a constant, whereas `check_form` is a variable. You can reassign variables easily. Reassigning a constant is difficult on purpose.

Comment: I see what you are saying. That was a mistake when I was typing my code into here this morning (It's Monday after all). My actual code does not have that set as a capital. (Sorry, it's been a crazy day so far).

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that there is a global variable where Ruby doesn't expect one. And there is: `$txtNumber` is a global variable, but it doesn't make sense for a global variable to appear at that place in your code.

Comment: The problem is that it's not a global variable it's part of the name for for the area that I am trying to set the value to so I can search.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to make it legal would be

```
Check_form.send(:"ct100$MainContent$txtNumber=", 'J520518')
```